# How to make mapper get data from files in orderly fashion

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

In my Input hdfs I have file1, file2, file3, file4.
I have written a mapper file in python to read data from these files using:

```
for lines in sys.stdin
```

the issue I am facing is it is reading line randomly from files, I want the code to read first file1 completely then file2 and go on.

MapperFile:

```
import sys
import os
s =''
i = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    if(line[i%40]=='|' and s[len(s)-1] != '\n'):
        s = s + '\n'
    elif(line[i%40]!='|'):
        s = s + line[i%40]
    i = i+1
print s
```

running this via streaming jar:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME//share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.0.jar -input /home/test/ -output /home/output6/ -mapper /home/eshobsa/hadoop_work/mapper.py
```

Can someone please guide me how can I make it read the lines from the file in sequence, i.e. first File1, then lines from file2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What you desire is a sequential scan of the input, which is not the case in mapreduce. In mapreduce, the files are scanned in parallel, which means that a mapper cannot know in what state the other mappers are and so, read the next file when the others are done reading a previous one. 
Actually, there is no such thing as 'previous' or 'next' file in mapreduce.

Are you sure that you need mapreduce? Judging from your description, you are not... Otherwise, are you sure, that you need a sequential scan of the input?